Path to sqlcmd in docker containers
I'm trying to create a docker container that would use sqlcmd to execute a couple scripts along with some other tasks, as such I attempted to create a container based off of mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools which can be found here. https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-tools. But when I try to run sqlcmd in the container I get the following error and running which sqlcmd reveals nothing.
# sqlcmd
/bin/sh: 1: sqlcmd: not found
# which sqlcmd
#

Now, I can run sqlcmd if I provide a path of /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd which is fine, but how could I get it so that I can just type in sqlcmd and run it? I can run sqlcmd just using sqlcmd if I build an container using docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools I'm assuming I'm missing a setup piece.
Here's an example of my dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools

ENTRYPOINT [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]


You might need to append the path to sqlcmd to the user's (in the Docker container) .bashrc file. Is the bash profile something you're familiar with?

You can append the path to sqlcmd to your .bashrc file as part of your Dockerfile. Try adding this line to it:
RUN echo "export PATH=/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd:${PATH}" >> /your_home_directory/.bashrc

You'd have to replace /your_home_directory with the path to your home directory within the container.

Most paths to running things in containers don't read .bashrc or similar dotfiles, and putting an export statement there will probably be ineffective.
